# Apollo/GraphQL not making query after new user logs in?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, graphql, apollo

I have this React component meant to only be rendered when a user is logged in and meant to display personalized recommendations to the currently logged in user.

The component makes queries to get the current user and the recommendations every time the authentication token is changed.

[image]

If I launch the application and log in with user1, everything is fine, but when I log out and log back in with user2, the recommendations page does not refresh and keeps showing the recommendations for the first user.

It seems that the problem is in **line 26**, as for some reason, for user2, the query getCurrentUser() is executed but nothing is retrieved, not even an error, and therefore the state is not updated despite the same exact query having worked for the first user. Am I not meant to use the same query twice like that?

Reloading the page does display the correct information.

Any idea of why this might be happening?

Comment: Does the `useEffect` gets fired? Can you `console.log` something inside the IF of your userEffect and see if it fires when the second user logins?

Comment: Yes the useEffect gets fired and if I put a console.log after the query function call it gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a bug with "onCompleted" in the current version of Apollo.

https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2177

Adding the fetchPolicy "cache-and-network" seems to be a workaround, thouth the solution seems sketchy.

```
  const [getCurrentUser, { loading: userLoading, data: userData }] = useLazyQuery(CURRENT_USER, {
fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
onCompleted: data => {
  getRecommendations({ variables: { favoriteGenre: data.me.favoriteGenre } })
}
```

})